# Does the browser instance from mechanize cache?

Tags: python, caching, mechanize

I am doing some webscraping with the mechanize browser and using the following code. I realized in some cases we keep getting the same page, although the remote page is already changed. So my question is:

1. Does mechanize broswer instance cache page by default (in some config)?
2. If so, how can we change it, or is there a way to avoid caching (apart from creating the browser instance every time in the loop we webscrape)

   ```
   # put int login detail and submit, return a mechanize.Browser instance 
   browser = _login() 
   # main loop
   while True:
       rsp = browser.open(URL)
       html = rsp.read()
   ```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216689),

> Mechanize instances do cache pages you've visited, but you can clear
>   that with agent.history.clear; or prevent history from being saved by
>   setting agent.history.max_size = 0. Or, you can use a new Mechanize
>   instance altogether.

Particularly,

> Currently Mechanize reuses pages in the history of the session if a
>   request with an If-Modified-Since header results in 304 Not Modified.

And by the documentation [here](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/old/mechanize/doc.html), in Python, the following code will prevent the caching-like behavior (seekable responses):

```
import mechanize
ua = mechanize.UserAgent()
ua.set_seekable_responses(False)
ua.set_handle_equiv(False)
ua.set_debug_responses(False)
```

Hope that provides some insight.

Comment: is it the mechanize for ruby or python? the link you post is for ruby?

Comment: @JohnZ The caching-like behavior appears to be the same throughout languages - I updated my answer with the specific Python code.

Comment: If you create a new instance `mechanize.Browser()` isn't that going to have a new empty cache?